# Webpack 2 Extract Text Plugin with Options

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to pass options to css loader, with new Webpack 2 config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: {
        discardComments: {
          removeAll: true,
        }
      },
    },
  }),
},
```

But the options are not working.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Minimize doesn't seem to have the parameters you are trying to call it with:

> By default the css-loader minimizes the css if specified by the module system.
>
> In some cases the minification is destructive to the css, so you can provide some options to it. cssnano is used for minification and you find a [list of options here](http://cssnano.co/options/).
>
> You can also disable or enforce minification with the minimize query parameter.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true || {/* CSSNano Options */}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Inside your `ExtractTextPlugin.extract()`, you shouldn't use `loader` and `options`, but rather `use`, `fallback` and `publicPath` (see [docu](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin)).
The `use` parameter takes the same parameters as the `use` parameter of the loader itself, so in the end you should get something like:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback : 'style-loader',
    use : {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        minimize: true || {/* CSSNano Options */}
      }
    }
  })
}
```

See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader
See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: How to do this with Extract Text Plugin? i.e. How to pass options to css-loader when we use Extract Text Plugin in css-loader's place?

Comment: The `use` description up there can also be used inside `ExtractTextPlugin.extract({})`. It takes `use` and `fallback`, according to the official documentation: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin